# Calling non const method in const method

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class B
{
  public:
  B(){}

  void g() { }
};

class A
{
 public:
 A()
 {
    ptr_ = std::make_shared<B>();  
 }

 void f() const 
 {
    ptr_->g(); // compile
    //obj_.g(); // doesn't compile as expected
 }

 std::shared_ptr<B> ptr_;
 B obj_;
};

int main()
{
  A a;
  a.f();
}
```

I am surprised that this piece of code builds fine. In A::f(), I call a non-const method of a data member. When this data member is a pointer it builds, if it is not a pointer it doesn't build as expected because B::g() is non-const.

Do you understand why I am able to call a non-const function inside a const function ?

Comment: Why you cannot? You call a non const method of another class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point is who is `const` in the `const` member function, the pointer ? the pointee ?

In the `const` member function `f`, `ptr_`, i.e. the pointer itself is considered as `const`, but not the object pointed by it. You're calling non-const member function `g` on the pointee, then it's fine.

Furthermore, you can't perform any modification (and call non-const member function) on the pointer `ptr_` itself (same as `obj_`), like `ptr_ = std::make_shared<B>();`; but you can do this on the object pointed by it, like `*ptr_ = B{};`.